# updating the parent and all its records child in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Query and below are the tables.

**Organization**

```
OrgID    Name          RAOGID     RAOID   SubGroupID   StatusID
1       Org RAOG1     1   NULL       NULL                2
2       Org RAO1            NULL       1        NULL      3
3       Org Sub Group1   NULL       NULL         1        1
4       Org RAOG2     2   NULL       NULL                2
5       Org RAO2            NULL       2        NULL      3
6       Org Sub Group2   NULL       NULL         2        2
```

**RAOG**

```
RAOGID  AccredID
1              2  
2              2  
3              2
```

**RAO**

```
RAOID   RAOGID
1         1
2         3
3         3
```

**Sub Group**

```
SubGroupID  RAOID
1            1
2            2
3            2
```

I have four tables as shown above, here is details of them,
1) Every RAOG, RAO and SUBGROUP are a organisation
2) RAOG can have many RAOs
3) RAO can have many SubGroups

I want to update my organisation table statusid, before updating I want to check if it is the RAOG type of oraganisation then it will update all the RAOs and SUBGROUPs under it and same with RAO it will update all the SUBGROUP under him it will not update it parent RAOG.And at last if it SUBGROUP type of organisation it will only update the subgroup not its parent records.

Thanks,
Best Regards,
Manoj

Comment: what DBMS is this? Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, something else?

Comment: Hi Jeff, Can you please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best acheived by wrapping the checks and calls you want to make into a stored procedure that you can then execute within a transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySprocOfDoom]

@param1             paramType,
    --...
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --SELECT statements here
END
```

Comment: Can you please write the code as I am not able to write sql code for it

Comment: Then perhaps you should not have been given a job where you need to write SQL

Comment: dear I am asking the logic code for above problem, I know very well about the SQL syntax, I am bit confused how i can get the above results. We can use function or procedure. Please give me the actual sql code?

Comment: I don't think it is reasonable for me to give you the code to a problem you are (presumably) being paid to solve yourself - do you? If you can write a SPROC, and SELECT statements and IF statements, then you're 90% of the way there - the other 10% is effort!